# Как получить штрихкод с USB сканнера в Android приложении?

Tags: android, usb, scanner

У меня есть Штрихкод сканнер, который подключается к устройству по OTG, как в приложении получить сам штрихкод, не используя какой-нибудь EditText? Я пытался использовать onKeyUp/onKeyDown, но там приходит всего 2 символа, мне же надо поймать с самого активити

Comment: Научитесь формулировать

Answer (score 0):

Решил эту проблему, надо использовать все таки метод onKeyUp, но при этом создать невидимый editText и поставить на него фокус